# How to get the Log Exceptions to email in Android?

Tags: android

I need to get or send all the log details or Exception to my email.

Comment: There are various tools for that. I myself use [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/) for it.

Comment: But i need to do it in my app without third party app

Answer (score 2):

```js
package tv.demogtelog;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;

import com.example.demogetlog.R;

public class ErrorReporter implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
 
  String VersionName;
  String PackageName;
  String FilePath;
  String PhoneModel;
  String AndroidVersion;
  String Board;
  String Brand;
 // String CPU_ABI;
  String Device;
  String Display;
  String FingerPrint;
  String Host; 
  String ID;
  String Manufacturer;
  String Model;
  String Product;
  String Tags;
  long Time;
  String Type;
  String User; 

  private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler PreviousHandler;
  private static ErrorReporter    S_mInstance;
  private Context       CurContext;
  
  public void Init( Context context )
  {
   PreviousHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
   Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( this );  
   RecoltInformations( context );
   CurContext = context;
  }
  
  public long getAvailableInternalMemorySize() { 
         File path = Environment.getDataDirectory(); 
         StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath()); 
         long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize(); 
         long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks(); 
         return availableBlocks * blockSize; 
     } 
      
  public long getTotalInternalMemorySize() { 
         File path = Environment.getDataDirectory(); 
         StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath()); 
         long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize(); 
         long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount(); 
         return totalBlocks * blockSize; 
     } 
  void RecoltInformations( Context context )
  {
   PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
         try
         {
          PackageInfo pi;
             // Version
             pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
             VersionName = pi.versionName;
             // Package name
             PackageName = pi.packageName;
             // Files dir for storing the stack traces
             FilePath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
             // Device model
             PhoneModel = android.os.Build.MODEL;
             // Android version
             AndroidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
            
             Board = android.os.Build.BOARD;
             Brand  = android.os.Build.BRAND;
             //CPU_ABI = android.os.Build.;
             Device  = android.os.Build.DEVICE;
             Display = android.os.Build.DISPLAY;
             FingerPrint = android.os.Build.FINGERPRINT;
          Host = android.os.Build.HOST;
          ID = android.os.Build.ID;
          //Manufacturer = android.os.Build.;
          Model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
          Product = android.os.Build.PRODUCT;
          Tags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
          Time = android.os.Build.TIME;
          Type = android.os.Build.TYPE;
          User = android.os.Build.USER;
            
         }
         catch (NameNotFoundException e)
         {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }
  }
  
  public String CreateInformationString()
  {
   String ReturnVal = "";
   ReturnVal += "Version : " + VersionName;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Package : " + PackageName;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "FilePath : " + FilePath;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Phone Model" + PhoneModel;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Android Version : " + AndroidVersion;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Board : " + Board;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Brand : " + Brand;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Device : " + Device;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Display : " + Display;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Finger Print : " + FingerPrint;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Host : " + Host;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "ID : " + ID;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Model : " + Model;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Product : " + Product;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Tags : " + Tags;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Time : " + Time;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Type : " + Type;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "User : " + User;
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Total Internal memory : " + getTotalInternalMemorySize();
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   ReturnVal += "Available Internal memory : " + getAvailableInternalMemorySize();
   ReturnVal += "\n";
   
   return ReturnVal;
  }
  

 @Override
 public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
    String Report = "";
    Date CurDate = new Date();
    Report += "Error Report collected on : " + CurDate.toString();
    Report += "\n";
    Report += "\n";
    Report += "Informations :";
    Report += "\n";
    Report += "==============";
    Report += "\n";
    Report += "\n";
    Report += CreateInformationString();
      
    Report += "\n\n";
    Report += "Stack : \n";
    Report += "======= \n";
    final Writer result = new StringWriter();
    final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
    e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    String stacktrace = result.toString();
    Report += stacktrace;

    Report += "\n";
    Report += "Cause : \n";
    Report += "======= \n";
    
    // If the exception was thrown in a background thread inside
    // AsyncTask, then the actual exception can be found with getCause
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    while (cause != null)
    {
     cause.printStackTrace( printWriter );
     Report += result.toString();
     cause = cause.getCause();
    }
    printWriter.close();
    Report += "****  End of current Report ***";
    SaveAsFile(Report);
    //SendErrorMail( Report );
    CheckErrorAndSendMail(CurContext);
    PreviousHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);
   }
   
   static ErrorReporter getInstance()
   {
    if ( S_mInstance == null )
     S_mInstance = new ErrorReporter();
    return S_mInstance;
  
 }
   
   private void SendErrorMail( Context _context, String ErrorContent )
   {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String subject = _context.getResources().getString( R.string.CrashReport_MailSubject );
    String body = _context.getResources().getString( R.string.CrashReport_MailBody ) +
     "\n\n"+
     ErrorContent+
     "\n\n";
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
      new String[] {"shoeb.siddique@techvalens.com"});
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    _context.startActivity( Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title:") );
   }
   private void SaveAsFile( String ErrorContent )
   {
    try
    {
     Random generator = new Random();
     int random = generator.nextInt(99999);
     String FileName = "stack-" + random + ".stacktrace";
     FileOutputStream trace = CurContext.openFileOutput( FileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     trace.write(ErrorContent.getBytes());
     trace.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
     // ...
    }
   }
   
   private String[] GetErrorFileList()
   {
    File dir = new File( FilePath + "/");
          // Try to create the files folder if it doesn't exist
          dir.mkdir();
          // Filter for ".stacktrace" files
          FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                  public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                          return name.endsWith(".stacktrace");
                  }
          };
          return dir.list(filter);
   }
   private boolean bIsThereAnyErrorFile()
   {
    return GetErrorFileList().length > 0;
   }
   public void CheckErrorAndSendMail(Context _context )
   {
    try
    {
     if ( bIsThereAnyErrorFile() )
     {
      String WholeErrorText = "";
      String[] ErrorFileList = GetErrorFileList();
      int curIndex = 0;
      // We limit the number of crash reports to send ( in order not to be too slow )
      final int MaxSendMail = 5;
      for ( String curString : ErrorFileList )
      {
       if ( curIndex++ <= MaxSendMail )
       {
        WholeErrorText+="New Trace collected :\n";
        WholeErrorText+="=====================\n ";
        String filePath = FilePath + "/" + curString;
        BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line;
        while (( line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
         WholeErrorText += line + "\n";
        }
        input.close();
       }

       // DELETE FILES !!!!
       File curFile = new File( FilePath + "/" + curString );
       curFile.delete();
      }
      SendErrorMail( _context , WholeErrorText );
     }
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using frameworks like [Crashlytics](https://www.crashlytics.com/). I used same it helps you track down crashes and exceptions as well rather than implementing your own :)

Comment: Thanks Virendrao.
But i need to do it in my app without third party app.

Comment: 1.You will need internet permission.
2. When you catch exception. copy stacktrace and paste it in subject of email intent.
3. to will be always your emailId

This steps you may follow. :) Cheers